# Open-Closed Principle in Python OOD

Tags: python, solid-principles, object-oriented-analysis, open-closed-principle

I am designing a parking lot. Now I have three kinds of parking spots. I want to initialize my parking lot like this:

```py
Building({Size.SMALL: 5, Size.MEDIUM: 6, Size.LARGE: 7})
```

This means this parking lot has

- 5 small spots,
- 6 medium spots and
- 7 large spots.

And below is my code for spots and the parking lot (i.e., Building).

```py
from enum import Enum

class Size(Enum):
    SMALL = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    LARGE = 3

class Spot:
    def __init__(self, id) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.vehicle = None

class SmallSpot(Spot):
    def __init__(self, id) -> None:
        super().__init__(id)

class MediumSpot(Spot):
    def __init__(self, id) -> None:
        super().__init__(id)

class LargeSpot(Spot):
    def __init__(self, id) -> None:
        super().__init__(id)

class Building:
    def __init__(self, dic: dict[Size, int]) -> None:
        for size, count in list(dic.items()):
            if size == Size.SMALL:
                self.small_spot_list = [SmallSpot(i) for i in range(count)]
            elif size == Size.MEDIUM:
                self.medium_spot_list = [MediumSpot(i) for i in range(count)]
            elif size == Size.LARGE:
                self.large_spot_list = [LargeSpot(i) for i in range(count)]
```

My question is, how can I rewrite the `__init__()` function of Building so that I don't need to explicitly write these enums in the code so that if there are new kinds of spots added, I will not need to modify the code in this function (such as add more if-else statements for new vehicle types)?

I believe it's called [Open-Closed Principle](https://www.educative.io/blog/solid-principles-oop-c-sharp#open-closed).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that when you say "new kinds of vehicles added" you mean new additions to your size enum:

```
from enum import Enum

class Size(Enum):
    SMALL = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    LARGE = 3
```

rather than inherit the base parking spot class, you could just include the `Size` enum as a property of the spot. Therefore:

```
class Spot:
    def __init__(self, id, size: Size) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.vehicle = None
        self.size = size # this will be a Size enum when initiating
```

Your building initialisation function can then be simplified:

- removed conditionals
- key of spot_dict: `Size`
- values of spot_dict: `list` of `Spots`

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self, dic: "dict[Size, int]") -> None:
        # initialise/save the variables
        self.spot_dict = {}
        self.vehicle_dict = dic
        
        # run the function to fill the lots
        self.fill_lots()
    
    def fill_lots(self):
        for size, count in self.vehicle_dict.items():
            self.spot_dict[size] = [Spot(i,size) for i in range(count)]
```

the benefits of this method allow you to find the spots in the specific `Size` category easily.

### Putting it all together

```
from enum import Enum

class Size(Enum):
    SMALL = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    LARGE = 3

class Spot:
    def __init__(self, id, size: Size) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.vehicle = None
        self.size = size

class Building:
    def __init__(self, dic: "dict[Size, int]") -> None:
        # initialise/save the variables
        self.spot_dict = {}
        self.vehicle_dict = dic
        
        # run the function to fill the lots
        self.fill_lots()
    
    def fill_lots(self):
        for size, count in self.vehicle_dict.items():
            self.spot_dict[size] = [Spot(i,size) for i in range(count)]
        
        
                
def main():
    building = Building({Size.SMALL: 5, Size.MEDIUM: 6, Size.LARGE: 7})
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

#### example of adding more categories

Assuming `Building` code stays the same:

```
class Size(Enum):
    SMALL = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    LARGE = 3
    HEAVY_VEHICLE = 4 # new kind
    OVERSIZED = 5 # new kind

bigger_building = Building({
            Size.SMALL: 5, 
            Size.MEDIUM: 6, 
            Size.LARGE: 7,
            Size.HEAVY_VEHICLE: 2,
            Size.OVERSIZED: 1,
            })
# access the list of spots
hv_vehicle_spot_ls = bigger_building.spot_dict[Size.HEAVY_VEHICLE]
```

Comment: What if I only want to use inheritance? Some spots may have unique attributes, such as chargers, and some may be for disabled drivers. How can I **dynamically** choose the type of slot I want to initiate just from my input?

Comment: Hm, I would add those in as attributes as well. You could think composition rather than inheritance here.

Comment: E.g. `self.ev_charge_spot = True` or `self.handicap_spot = True`. You would then have to include more parameters, and change the `fill_spots` method. Hope this helps